JS Error: Uncaught TypeError: ".year-link".click is not a function
I have the following JS code:
(".year-link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    var year = $(this).data("year");  
    var url = window.location.pathname + '?action=year&year=' + year;
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        var receivedData = $(data);  // Convert the received HTML data to a jQuery object
        var posts = receivedData.find('.fenster').html();  // Extract the posts data
        $('.fenster').html(posts);  // Update the current page with the received posts data
    });
});

The code is used in a Django template as follows:
{% for jahr in jahre %}
    <div class="flex-item" style="flex-basis: 10%;">
        <a href="?action=year&year={{jahr}}" class="year-link">{{ jahr }} </a>
    </div>


The code does what it should (!!) but produces an error, seen in the developer tools:

JS Error: Uncaught TypeError: ".year-link".click is not a function

If I wrap my year-link function with document.ready, the error is gone, but the page loses its behavior (nothing happens after click):
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".year-link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();  
        var year = $(this).data("year");  
        var url = window.location.pathname + '?action=year&year=' + year;
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            var receivedData = $(data);  // Convert the received HTML data to a jQuery object
            var posts = receivedData.find('.fenster').html();  // Extract the posts data
            $('.fenster').html(posts);  // Update the current page with the received posts data
        });
    });
});

What am I to do?
I tried with ChatGPT for several days, but either the code does what it should and produces the JS error, or the code produces no error and does nothing.

In your first codeblock there is missing a $ in front of your selector:
(".year-link") -> $(".year-link")
Also your a tag seems to have no data attribute year so $(this).data("year") will not return anything.
consider to add the attribute data-year="{{jahr}}".

Thank-you. The error has gone.

But the second suggestion I cannot realize: where am I to do what?

@AndreasA the code $(this).data("year") makes sense if the clicked element has an attribute data-year="1985" (for example). None of your HTML elements have such an attribute, so it's not clear how you expect that to work.

For more clarity, this: <a href="?action=year&year={{jahr}}" data-year="{{jahr}}" class="year-link">{{ jahr }} </a>  Using $(this).data('year') is the jQuery equivalent of element.getAttribute('data-year')
